# json is not parsing correctly in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to parse my JSON into an NSDictionary. Here is the method that I use for parsing.

```
+ (NSDictionary *)executeGenkFetch:(NSString *)query
{
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", query];
    query = [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"[%@ %@] sent %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), query);
    NSData *jsonData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *results = jsonData ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error] : nil;
    if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] JSON error: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error.localizedDescription);
     NSLog(@"[%@ %@] received %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), results);
    return results;
}
```

And here is how I use this function.

```
+(NSArray *)getCommentsWithParam:(NSString *)Param
{
    NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=%@",Param];
    NSLog(@"request is %@",request);
    NSString *vfk = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.comments.data",Param];
    return [[self executeGenkFetch:request] valueForKey:vfk];
}
```

The problem is when I log the NSArray that I get back from getCommentsWithParam, I always get NULL. But when I look at the log from

```
 NSLog(@"[%@ %@] received %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), results);
```

I get the JSON I want. Any help on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is difficult to say without seeing the actual JSON data, but probably in

```
NSString *vfk = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.comments.data",Param];
return [[self executeGenkFetch:request] valueForKey:vfk];
```

you have to use `valueForKeyPath` instead of `valueForKey`, because `vfk` is a *key path* with several key components (separated by the dots).

***Update:*** Another problem is that the top-level key `Param` is a HTTP URL and contains dots. But in key-value coding dots are used to separate the key components. Therefore you cannot use `Param` as a key component. Use `objectForKey` for the top-level key instead:

```
NSDictionary *results = [self executeGenkFetch:request];
return [[results objectForKey:Param] valueForKeyPath:@"comments.data"];
```

Comment: Martin R, If you want to see the JSON data you can go to here. https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.krcgenk.be//nl/nieuws/show/barda-en-vossen-twijfelachtig-voor-kv-kortrijk/1330

Comment: ValueForKeyPath is also not working. But when I log the NSDictionary results in the executeGenkFetch. I get the correct dictionary

Comment: Try something like NSDictionary *result = [[[self executeGenkFetch:request] objectForKey:@"comments"] objectForKey:@"data"]; Then for(NSDictionary *dict in result) {//do something with comment info}

Comment: @StefGeelen: Please see my updated answer, I hope that it works now.